# Conflicting values for resource

Tags: uwp, windows-10-iot-core

I'm working on a **windows 10 IoT project** (so built in **uwp**). At the begining I created the app as a *blank app (universal)* but when I try to build it I have 2 errors:

> Processing resources failed with error: multiple entry
>
> Conflicting values for resource 'Files/MainPage.xbf

This 2 errors come from the file

> MakePri

I don't understand the problem and how to solve it as I have only one **MainPage** in my project...

Answer (score 6):

I just found the reason of the error.
In fact, I was referencing an app in my project ( so this app was containing another mainpage ) I deleted the reference and everything works fine

Comment: Deleted the reference?! So what if you need to keep the reference??

Comment: Just stumbled upon this issue as well, I suggest moving the common resources to a separate project and only referencing that.